# SQL server 2000 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2000, pentaho

I have this question for you guys. I have to transfer SQL server 2000 to MySQL. What i mean is that there are some transformation to add information to tables with corrections or anything the company needs to add and modify. They have SQL server 2000 transformation and i need to **convert** those **selects, inserts, updates** into `MySQL`.

I would like to know if SQL server 2000 `INNER JOIN` is the same as `MySQL INNER JOIN`.

If it is the case, i would not have to modify anything and i could just copy those selects etc... into MySQL.

I will use Spoon from BI Pentaho to make those transformation as they are leaving SQL Server behind.

Thanks alot for your answers !

Comment: Why can't you just **[Google](https://encrypted.google.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to bring the data straight over then why are you using an ETL tool? I'd have thought a straight migration would be easier?  The ETL tool will in this case be more work.

ETL tool is fair enough if you want to make some changes to the data on the way.

How about this:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/08/MySQL-Migration

( There are lots of ways to dump data straight across )

Comment: I think i'll need to change some queries on the way of migrating them. Is that possible with the migration option given with MySQL workbench ? Will it change the selects accordingly to the rules of MySQL correctly ? It is important data which has to be perfectly aligned with the original SQL server 2000.
**IMPORTANT**: To add more precision to this post, i need to migrate Data Transformation Services (dts) of SQL Server 2000 to MySQL is that possible with the migrate system of MySQL ? Can i simply migrate those **dts** to my MySQL ? Or should i use a ETL tool as you said ?

Comment: No, you cannot migrate dts to mysql - these will need to be reimplemented in some other technology.  Sounds like you need to do more research.

Comment: I think i found a solution i'm going to translate those DTS to an ETL Tool named Kettle from PDI Pentaho Data Integration ! 
Thanks anyways !

Comment: Ah ok; I was misled by the name - I thought a DTS meant a genuine service (i.e. a server sitting there serving data a'la composite) not just an ETL process. So yes, Kettle will easily do what you need!  Saying that kettle can even do data services these days anyway!  ( well from 5.0 it can )